# Load multiple files using a relative path in a for loop

Tags: r, path

I have a subdirectory of my project folder containing 50 .csv files. I know how to load them using a for loop and an absolute file path.
However, I would like to load them using a relative file path, so its easier to hand the project to others. Below you see the code, in which I already wrote the relative path, which is working if an absolute path is used.

```
list.filenames.field <- list.files(path = "./data_field/", pattern = ".csv$")
list.data.field <- list()
for (i in 1:length(list.filenames.field))
{                                                 
  list.data.field[[i]] <- read.csv("./data_field/list.filenames.field[[i]]", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

How can a relative file path can be used when reading files using a for loop?

Comment: Do you use RStudio? This is the sort of thing RStudio project files manage.

Comment: Yes, I use RStudio. How can this be managed by a project fiel? I haven't worked with projects much.

Comment: It's like a better way of `setwd()`. Have a read of https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects

Comment: Maybe I don't get your suggestion, but I am working in a RStudio project, since the directory and all. So maybe my question should be "How to unquote a vector object in double quotes" or something like that...? I am happy about any ideas.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to refer to all subdirectories for a main directory without explicitly writing them, you can use `subfolders  <- list.dirs(recursive = F)` to get all relative paths. Use another variable for your working directory (`base_path`). Then use something like `lapply(subfolders, function(z){ myReadFunc(path = paste(base_path, z, sep = ""))})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me, not sure if it is the most efficient though.

```
listFilenames <- list.files(path = "./data_field/", pattern = ".csv$")
listData<- list()
path <- list()
for (i in 1:length(listFilenames ))
{ 
  path[[i]] <- paste0("./data/",listFilesnames[[i]])                                                
  listData[[i]] <- read.csv("./data/listFilenames [[i]]", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```